# Laravel sanctum scope for nuxtjs frontend

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

So i'm trying to establish some kind of policy inbetween the frontend and backend, all works fine however i'm a little confused towards declaring a scope for my application users

```
ApiSessionController.php

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    $token = $user->createToken(
        'token',
        ['role' => $user->getRoleNames()->first()]
    );

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return response()->json('', 204);
    } else {
        return response()->json('Invalid credentials', 403);
    }
}
```

I do realize that this code doesn't currently uses the token, however i see no change when i

return response()->json($token, 200);

---

```
Nuxt.js frontend default.vue

<v-btn v-if="this.$auth.hasScope('admin')">admin</v-btn>
<v-btn v-else>No admin</v-btn>
```

Now, i've read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum many, many times - 
and

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function(Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});
```

returns my user fine, however i have no idea how to create the scope in the backend, through a token (i assume?) and accessing that scope in the frontend nuxtjs.

Comment: auth section nuxt.config.js

`auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: 'v1/session',
      logout: '/login',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'v1/session', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          user: { url: 'v1/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
          logout: { url: 'v1/session', method: 'delete'}
        },
        tokenRequired: false,
        tokenType: false
      }
    },
    localStorage: false
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for now :)
Explanation: Set a scope, when nuxtjs retrieves your user information from the laravel GET user call

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function(Request $request) {
 $user = $request->user();
 $user['scope'] = $user->insertScopeMethod();
 return $user;
});
```